# Compile Loadable Kernel Module and User Application with one Makefile - Linux

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Recently I am getting a first step on developing a device driver.
And I wrote some piece of junk code to understand the interaction between user application and device module via device file.

So, I wrote user application and device driver and was willing to compile those files with a single makefile.

But when I tried to do so, it did not work out. Here is the code that I wrote :

```
KERNELDIR = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

obj-m := deviceJino.o

PWD := $(shell pwd)

default:
        $(MAKE) -c $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) moudles
```

Above code is device driver makefile.
and following code is user app makefile.

```
userApplication : userApplication.o
      gcc - o userApplication userApplication.o

userApplication.o : userApplication.c
      gcc -c userApplication.c

clean : 
       rm *.o userApplication
```

These two makefiles work properly when they are in different dir. But I when I combine these two makefiles into one and put all dependent sources into one directory, it does not work.

Plz tell me how to combine those codes into one single Makefile ?

Comment: If by "it does not work" you mean that on `make` the device driver is built but user part is not, then this is because your `default` rule - the first rule in the combined Makefile - is unaware about `userApplication` rule. You may replace `default:` line with `default: userApplication`.

Comment: There are a couple of typos: `-c` should be `-C` and `moudles` should be `modules`.